# よろしく as particle/adverb meaning ように？

Tags: grammar, particles, comparison

Recently I came across an unfamiliar usage of よろしくnamely よろしくas an particle? adverb? Probably it means something like ～ように。I was told it gives the sentence an "ironic" nuance but I am not sure how to understand that and couldn't really find further information on it.
How does one use よろしく in this sense and how would your interpretation of the examples below be?

> 「全員、中学生なんだ」アキが言った。全員のまとめ役**よろしく**、みんなを見渡して頷く。

> 「食べられるっていうのは文字通りの意味で？」と彼女が続けた。”オオカミさま”が頷いた。「そりゃもう、頭から丸のみ」。
> 「ただし、童話**よろしく**お母さんを呼んできて腹かっさばいて、かわりに石を詰めるとかやめろよ。充分に気を付けるように」

About the story: Seven kids meet in an parallel universe and a mysterious girl called　オオカミさま is explaining the rules of this world to them. She claims that if they break the rules they get eaten by a wolf.

My guess would be よろしく modifies the preceding noun giving it the nuance of "even though it's not x treating it as it were x".

- "even though she is not the mediator/leader acting like she would be"
- "even though it's not a fairy tale treating it like one"
  But I have no confidence at all in this interpretation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interpretations are correct.

[A dictionary definition](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%AE%9C%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F/#jn-228655) says

> 上の内容を受けて、いかにもそれらしく、の意を表す。「喜劇俳優宜しくおどけてみせる」

Some comments:

- I agree that this よろしく is used like a particle, but it is an adverb all the same.
- Your interpretation *even though it is not X* is not off, but it is more simply *exactly like X* or *as if it were X* (which I think already contains the meaning that the thing is not X).
- Just in case, the 童話 refers to [赤ずきん](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Red_Riding_Hood).

Comment: Thank you :) Do you know what kind of connotation it adds to the sentence. How it differs from  ～ように？

Comment: One thing I'm sure is that Xよろしく is unlikely to be used by younger people, even if not impossible. Another thing is that some prefer one or the other due to the difference of sounds (with or without the long vowel in **よー**に). In general, Xよろしく is more for writing.

Comment: @CaRina I think this use of よろしく is limited to contexts of someone imitating/mimicking someone else (intentionally or unintentionally).