# Usage of よろしく with a noun?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

My understanding was that よろしく is mainly used to make requests or to thank someone for but in the following example it seems to be used in a context more like "In regards too"

> ローラー作戦**よろしく**、地元の刑事にも動員をかけたいところだったが、どこから情報が漏れているのかも分からない状況では、かかわる人数は最低限にしたかった。

Just wondering if that interpretation is correct and if that is another usage of よろしく or have I misunderstood its usage.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/90257/9831

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means "just like a ローラー作戦".

Jisho.org

> Expressions (phrases, clauses, etc.), Adverb (fukushi)
> 3. just like ...; as though one were ...​ (Usually written using kana alone, as ...よろしく)

dictionary.goo.ne.jp

> ５ 上の内容を受けて、いかにもそれらしく、の意を表す。「喜劇俳優―おどけてみせる」